# How to mark Messages as read with apple script?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I was wondering if there is a way to mark messages from either a particular thread/user and/or just mark all as read. Preferable per thread. I can see there is a way to do this for the Mail app for example:

```
    on run {}


   tell application "Mail"


      set read status of every message of mailbox "Deleted Items" of account "MyAccount" to true


   end tell


end run
```

But need to be able to do the same for the Messages App instead.

Comment: something i will need to do frequently.

Comment: Shame.  There's only one way I can think of doing it.  When a message is selected in the _Messages_ app, the unread messages become read.  Therefore, programmatically selecting each message one-by-one would, in theory, mark them as read in turn.  It's inelegant, and suitable for a one-time scenario, but probably not the nicest thing to have to sit through regularly.